# Async Await Timeout

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5, async-await

I am writing a simple method that validates a webpage url is real and returns either True or False.

Using the new async await functions in .NET 4.5 this now seems ridiculously easy, but how do I set a timeout for async?

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns True if a webpage is valid.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="url">Url of the webpage.</param>
Private Async Function VailiateWebpageAsync(url As String) As Task(Of Boolean)       
    Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse

    httpRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    httpRequest.Method = "HEAD" 'same as GET but does not return message body in the response

    Try
        httpResponse = CType(Await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync, HttpWebResponse)
    Catch ex As Exception
        httpResponse = Nothing
    End Try

    If Not IsNothing(httpResponse) Then
        If httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            httpResponse.Dispose()
            Return True
        End If
    End If

    If Not IsNothing(httpResponse) Then httpResponse.Dispose()
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` has a `Timeout` property that you can set:

[*MSDN: HttpWebRequest.Timeout*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx)

If the timeout is exceeded, a `WebException` will be thrown with the [`Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) property set to `Timeout` which you can then catch and handle.

Comment: this is a sensible answer to the problem - but how do you set a timeout for the async part as well?

Comment: @geo1701 If a timeout happens in `GetResponseAsync`, then your `await` call will throw the exception and you can catch it in a normal catch block - that's a normal part of `async / await`

Comment: Just set it right after you set the Method - it should enforce that Timeout on its own. You shouldn't need to do so manually.

Answer (score 4):

Per the author's comment, I gather he wants to be able to timeout ANY async.  This is the method I use on .NET 4 on get a 10 second timeout.  Syntax will vary slightly on .NET 4.5 because they replaced the static methods on the `TaskEx` class with the `Task` class.

```
        var getUserTask = serviceAgent.GetAuthenticatedUser();
        var completedTask = await TaskEx.WhenAny(getUserTask, TaskEx.Delay(10000));

        if (completedTask != getUserTask)
        {
            Log.Error("Unable to contact MasterDataService to retrieve current user");
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to contact the server to retrieve your user account.  Please try again or contact support.");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```

This code will kick off the `GetAuthenticatedUser` asynchronous task but will not hold on that line because there is no `await` there.  Instead it moves onto the next line and awaits **either** the getUserTask or a 10 second delay.  Whichever completes first will cause that line's `await` to return. We can determine whether the timeout occurred by examining the `Task` returned by `TaskEx.WhenAny` or by querying `getUserTask` and looking at its Status

Answer (score 0):

Before making the call, set the timeout value in milliseconds:

```
myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 1234
```

Details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx).

Comment: this is a sensible answer to the problem - but how do you set a timeout for the async part as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Timeout yourself via `Task.Delay`.

Note, that `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` property is *IGNORED* for async calls. It is clearly stated in MSDN:

==================================

The Timeout property has no effect on asynchronous requests made with the BeginGetResponse or BeginGetRequestStream method.

In the case of asynchronous requests, the client application implements its own time-out mechanism. Refer to the example in the BeginGetResponse method.

==================================